# Extracting text from pdf containing multiple columns with pdfplumber (Python)

Tags: python, multiple-columns, text-extraction

I am extracting texts from pdfs (with python) in order to analyze them so I am working a lot with scientific papers. I am using **pdfplumber** and it is working excellent the only problem is that such pdfs usually contain **columns** and I haven't found a way for my algorithm to recognize this.

My code is:

```
text = ""
with pdfplumber.open(r'example.pdf') as pdf:
    pages = pdf.pages
    for i, pg in enumerate(pages):
        text = text + " " + pages[i].extract_text(x_tolerance = 1)
text = text.replace('\n',' ')
text = text.replace('\r',' ')
text = text.replace('\no',' ')
text = text.replace('\nD',' ')
text = text.lower()
text = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]', ' ', text)
```

do you know a function that might help me? Thank you!

Comment: Is the problem solved? Can you update on the status

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the columns are separated by `" "` then you can use the `draw_rects()` function to craft out the text from the columns.

The process requires you to detect the `chars` and `spaces` first using

```
im.reset().draw_rects(p0.chars)
```

And then using

```
text = p0.extract_text()
```

will give you the text format of the columns. This example illustrates how it can be done - [Extract the column text from the PDF](https://render.githubusercontent.com/view/ipynb?commit=3afd08620f345adbf60d5a21c1e201535745239f&enc_url=68747470733a2f2f7261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6a7376696e652f706466706c756d6265722f336166643038363230663334356164626636306435613231633165323031353335373435323339662f6578616d706c65732f6e6f7465626f6f6b732f73616e2d6a6f73652d70642d6669726561726d2d7265706f72742e6970796e62&nwo=jsvine%2Fpdfplumber&path=examples%2Fnotebooks%2Fsan-jose-pd-firearm-report.ipynb&repository_id=41279279&repository_type=Repository#See-where-the-characters-are-on-the-page)